# Iterating through a file with old/new values and changing to new values in a separate file

Tags: xml, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have an XML file with that contains a list of old IDs that need to be changed to new IDs.

Ex:

```xml
<faketag>189852226</faketag>
<faketag>189851254</faketag>
<faketag>189851257</faketag>
<faketag>189851284</faketag>
<faketag>189851263</faketag>
<faketag>189851608</faketag>
```

I have another file that contains the old ID and the new ID that should replace them.

```
old       new
189852226 192681118
189851254 192681121
189851257 192681124
189851284 192681127
189851263 192681130
189851608 192681133
```

What would be the best practice method for iterating through the list above, and replacing old IDs with the new ones in the XML file, en masse?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at xmlstarlet. This should be straightforward (ish)

Comment: Can the same ID be on more than one line?

Comment: @RamanSailopal yes, the IDs will appear twice in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is really that restricted and regular and assuming you can't use xmlstarlet or similar for some reason then:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{map[$1]=$2; next} $3 in map{sub($3,map[$3])} 1' oldnewids FS='[<>]' file.xml
<faketag>192681118</faketag>
<faketag>192681121</faketag>
<faketag>192681124</faketag>
<faketag>192681127</faketag>
<faketag>192681130</faketag>
<faketag>192681133</faketag>
```

Comment: I will consider this as an accepted answer.  It's actually what I am looking for, using a built-in.  I don't consider 'just use xmlstarlet' an acceptable answer because it makes the assumption that there will be no issue installing this 3rd party package on any distribution.

Answer (score -1):

I found a quite simple but very slow way to do this.

```sh
while read a b
    do
    sed -i "s/$a/$b/g" file.xml
done < oldnewids
```

I would consider this an accepted answer,  but faster methods are welcome!

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and you were already advised to look into using xmlstarlet - did you?

Comment: Yes, I did, and there were too many issues getting the package to install correctly on debian due to an issue with /etc/ld.cache.so  that I did not have time to investigate and resolve.  The loop, while not a best practice, still produced the expected result.